# How to return the real type from async Lambda expression (not wrapped as Task)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my code bellow, `postsVM` is of type `IEnumerable<Task<PostViewModel>>`.
How can I return `IEnumerable<PostViewModel>` (without `Task`) instead?

```
var postsVM = posts.Select(async p => new PostViewModel
{
    PostId = p.Id,
    PostContent = p.Content,
    PostTitle = p.Title,
    WriterAvatarUri = fileService.GetFileUri(p.Writer.Profile.AvatarId, Url),
    WriterFullName = p.Writer.Profile.FullName,
    WriterId = p.WriterId,
    Liked = await postService.IsPostLikedByUserAsync(p.Id, userId),
    LikesCount = await postService.GetPostLikesCountAsync(p.Id)
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<PostViewModel> results = await Task.WhenAll(postsVM);
```

More precisely, `Task.WhenAll(postVM)` will return a `Task<PostViewModel[]>` that completes when all of the tasks passed to it have completed, so awaiting that then gets you a `PostViewModel[]` which you could use as that type, or as `IEnumerable<PostViewModel>` as suits.

Comment: So in this case, multiple `select` processes will be happening in parallel, i.e., my array elements are being built in parallel, and when all of them finish, I will get the result, is that correct?

Comment: Yup. the `WhenAll` gets all the results when they're available.